# How to apply CKEDitor 5 Bold Plugin to my own inline elements

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I followed the *Implementing an inline widget* tutorial at https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/tutorials/implementing-an-inline-widget.html.

I want to extend it to enable bolding of placeholders.

I added `this.editor.model.schema.extend( 'placeholder', { allowAttributes: 'bold' } );` to `PlaceholderEditing.init()`, so it now looks like this:

```
    init() {
        this._defineSchema();
        this._defineConverters();

        this.editor.commands.add('placeholder', new PlaceholderCommand(this.editor));

        this.editor.editing.mapper.on(
            'viewToModelPosition',
            viewToModelPositionOutsideModelElement(this.editor.model, viewElement => viewElement.hasClass('placeholder'))
        );
        this.editor.config.define( 'placeholderConfig', {
            types: [ 'date', 'first name', 'surname' ]
        } );
        this.editor.model.schema.extend( 'placeholder', { allowAttributes: 'bold' } ); //ADDED
    }
```

Then I wrapped my placeholder in `<strong></strong>`, like so:

`<strong><span class="placeholder" >{mike}</span></strong>`

The inspector shows me the attribute gets added to `placeholder` in the model, like so:

[image]

But, the rendered html in the editor does not have `<strong></strong>` downcast on it

[image]

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to do this cleanly currently.  There is already an issue for it: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1633